# How to get current date time in the format 2019101620000583?

Tags: java, datetime, java-6

I am new to Java. I am trying to store current date time in long format, like 2019110820000583.

I tried using `System.currentTimeMillis()` but it doesn't give date and time combined. It gives me result like `1573205716048`.

Comment: Could you please share whatever have you tried?

Comment: I tried `System.currentTimeMillis()` and the below code.```Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    long millisecondsDate = date.getTimeInMillis();```

Comment: Have you read the documentation about what `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `date.getTimeInMillis()` returns?

Comment: **Read about `java.time`…** You can have a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS")` there and format every `LocalDateTime` accordingly.

Comment: Ok I found a way myself.```String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());``` It gives result like ***20191108095117***

Comment: Do you intend UTC or a time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *java.time*

Get the current moment in UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Define a formatting pattern for your desired output.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmss" ) ;
```

Generate a String with text in your desired format.

```
String output = odt.format( f ) ;
```

For a time zone, similar to code above but use `ZonedDateTime` in place of `OffsetDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
```

### ISO 8601

Tip: Generally best to use the standard ISO 8601 formats when serializing date-time values as text. To comply with the “basic” version of ISO 8601:

- insert a `T` between the date portion and the time-of-day portion.
- Append a `Z` for a moment in UTC. Otherwise append the offset.

So this:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssXXXXX" )
```

See this full example [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/6LYqyx).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssXXXXX" ) ;
String output = odt.format( f ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2019-11-09T04:38:47.972145Z
>
> output: 20191109T043847Z

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: @OleV.V. Done. Thanks.